# How to get a mutable reference to the contents of the Box<dyn T>?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Say I have a trait:

```
trait ReactorClient<S : Source + ?Sized> {
    fn get_source(&self) -> S;
}
```

And a method that accepts Box<dyn ReactorClient>:

```
fn register<S : Source + ?Sized>(&self, mut client: Box<dyn ReactorClient<S>>, token: Token, interests: Interest) -> io::Result<()>
```

Inside this method, how do I go from `Box<dyn ReactorClient<S>>` to `&mut S`? So far every attempt ends with something like `the size of` S `cannot be statically determined`.

I tried `&mut client.get_source()`, `&mut client.as_mut().get_source()` etc - with no luck.

Feels like fundamentally I need to do something else to avoid dereferencing S?

Comment: Why is `S` `?Sized` if you're returning it by value? As a mutable reference, do you want to modify the source within your reactor client? Or just mutate a copy?

Comment: `get_source` returns an entire `S` object, either a new one or moving it out of `self` somehow, but that requires that the compiler know how big it is to hold it. You say in your description you want a `&mut S`, so you should probably edit `get_source` to return that.

Comment: S is ?Sized because the library I'm calling into wants it that way

Comment: This is probably an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you step back and tell us what you are trying to accomplish, including details about the library you are trying to use?

Comment: Well, the library is mio and I need &mut S to pass to: self.poll.registry().register(client.get_source(), token, interests) (https://docs.rs/mio/latest/mio/struct.Registry.html#method.register). I can see that the option to return &mut S instead of S actually works, so maybe it's all I need really.

Comment: Everything that is `Sized` is automatically `?Sized` - by enforcing it in your trait, you don't actually gain anything, but instead make it impossible to return an `S`.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that you fundamentally get wrong is that if you want to have an `&mut S`, you should actually return a `&mut S`, not an `S`.

If you return an **owned** instance of `S`, it will no longer be the one inside of the `ReactorClient`. No matter what you write around it, like `&mut client.get_source()` or `&mut client.as_mut().get_source()` will change that fact.

So the thing you should change is the return value of your `get_source()` function to a `&mut S`. Further, you probably want the function to be `&mut self`, otherwise you can't really return a `&mut S`.

```rust
pub trait Source {}

pub trait ReactorClient<S: Source + ?Sized> {
    fn get_source(&mut self) -> &mut S;
}

// A function that demonstrates that our API works:
pub fn foo<S: Source + ?Sized>(mut obj: Box<dyn ReactorClient<S>>) {
    // This line demonstrates what you asked for: converting a
    // `Box<dyn ReactorClient<S>>` to a `&mut S`
    let _s: &mut S = obj.get_source();
}
```